# Upgrading from TFS 2013 to Azure DevOps 2019 On-Prem (inheritance process model)

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, upgrade

We have successfully upgraded to  Azure DevOps 2019 On-Prem from TFS 2013, however, the collection is automatically create under the XML process model.

I understand that the documentation clearly say that you cannot upgrade to the inheritance process model directly, however, now i want to know how can i switch the XML collection to the inheritance process model  for the upgraded collection, or even migrate everything to a new collection.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to convert from on-premise XML to inherited on Azure DevOps Server, and product team have made the decision to not build this feature:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/614232/bring-inherited-process-to-existing-projects-for-a.html

You would have the following choices:

1. Move to the Azure DevOps Service
2. Create a new inherited collection and continue your project work within that collection.